# laravel URL problem http://127.0.0.1:8000/ %09/posts/edit/3

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a problem with my laravel URL
I make a one-user blog, but when I click on modify button the URL is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ %09 /posts/edit/3
the problem is in /%09/...
this is the route

```
Route::get('/posts/edit/{post}' , [PostController::class , 'edit'])->name('posts.edit');
```

and this is the href

```
href="{{route('posts.edit' , ['post' => $post->id])}}"
```

Comment: Check the value of your APP_URL environment variable. Make sure there's no hidden spaces in there

Comment: There are no hidden spaces in APP_URL

Answer (score 0):

see you can pass variable directly with out reference if you have only 1 parameter

like this:
Route::get('/posts/edit/{post}' , [PostController::class , 'edit'])->name('posts.edit');

href="{{ route('posts.edit' , $post->id) }}"

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your codebase, there is a `Horizontal Tab` that is being parsed in URL. This is the reason you are seeing `%09`.